# Typescript: Type assertion as any, what does this mean?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, casting, react-redux, assertion

I am trying to understand how a section of code works. I have seen type assertion before but for some reason I can't wrap my head around this.

```
(this.whatever as any).something([]);
```

Larger section of code:

```
    resetThis(): void {
    if (this.whatever) {
        (this.whatever as any).something([]);
    }
}
```

When trying to run this block I get the error: `this.whatever.someting is not a function`

Comment: It asserts `this.whatever` is `any`. Which then means that you can access any property from it.

Comment: so the .something would be the property they/I am trying to access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to this plain JavaScript code:

```
this.whatever.something([]);
```

When you say `as any` in TypeScript, you're telling the compiler to ignore the previous type of the preceding expression and instead treat it as if it were of the `any` type. So in your case, you're telling the compiler that `this.whatever` is of type `any`.

The `any` type in TypeScript is basically a type that means "we don't know anything about what this variable really is, so let me do whatever I want with it". The TypeScript handbook describes it as ["opting out of typechecking"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any).

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `this.whatever` has type `IMyType`.

With:

```
IMyType {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: string;
}
```

so if you call `this.whatever.something([])`, the compiler will scream. Because the `something([])` function is not defined in `IMyType`.

Using `as any` will tell the compiler that for that specific statement, it should consider `this.whatever` to be of type `any`. Which means it can have any property or method it wants.